# Badge Logo in UWP scale 400 giving error in appmanifest file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, uwp

There is already an image as BadgeLogo.png and a scale 400 image included in the image folder still the build shows the below error

```
App manifest references the image 'images\BadgeLogo.png' which does not have a candidate in main app package.
```

Comment: How is the image referenced within the project and the code? Please include more information. To get an idea of how to construct a great post, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you building on Visual Studio Team services?

Comment: this might be caused by a naming conflict check the app manifest visual assets.
try removing all references and then add this again

Comment: @RamiSarieddine thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moving the comment to an answer.

This issues might be caused by a naming conflict (I faced the same once).
Check the app manifest visual assets. try removing all references and then add this image again. then clean and build. that should solve it.